# flex AIR application controlbar for Windows & MAC

Tags: apache-flex, macos, air

In my flex AIR application(with systemChrome=false & showFlexChrome=false) I am using ApplicationControlbar as the title bar with title text, close, max, min, button. It work fine on windows platform. But I have problem on MAC platform. My application shows close, max, min buttons on right & title text on left.
But my requirement is on windows it should be like it is & on Mac the title bar should show close, max min buttons on left.

I tried to identify the platform on which the application is running but I was not able to get that. I don't know how but creating two css & applying accordingly would work but don't know how to implement it.

PLease help me in acheiving either.

Answer (score 1):

see [flash.system::Capabilities.os](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os)

But why don't you use chrome but trying to create same elements...

Comment: I have my custom buttons for max, restore, min, close & title text. And also the spacing between the buttons & the title text spacing from border is different. I didn't find any way to set these properties so I took Application controlbar -> Canvas then labels & buttons in it. Please correct me if I am taking wrong apprach.